# What is the Laplace transform of this function?

Tags: laplace-transform, inverse-laplace

Let us say I have a function in the Laplace domain F(s) whose inverse Laplace transform is f(t). Is there some theorem/identity/derivation such that I can find the inverse Fourier transform of F(s)/(s-a)?

Comment: Hint: Convolution.

Answer (score 0):

My hint from the comments:

> Use the convolution theorem. Suppose $(f, F)$ and $(g, G)$ are transform pairs. Then $$ \mathcal{L} (f \star g) = \mathcal{L}(f) \mathcal{L}(g), $$ where $\star$ is convolution.

The crux:

> Note that $$\mathcal{L} \left( e^{-at} \right) = \frac{1}{s-a}.$$ Now use the above.

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks for the hint. I have thought of this earlier; I end up with the convolution of the function with the (e^(-at)); I was wondering is there a way to simplify and get an answer without convolution in terms of f(t) (or related derivatives or integrands), or would the end result of the convolution be dependent on the functional form of f(t) that no further simplification can be made?